# toString('base64') In Node Returns Invalid Image Data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have a website where I send a `GET` request to the server and expect it to download an image from a website and send the data back to the client. If I write the resulting data from the download directly to a file, it works.

```
    app.get('/image', function(req, res) {
    request("http://ipcam/auto.jpg", {encoding: 'binary'}, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        fs.writeFile('logo ' + (Math.random() * 1000).toFixed(0) + '.jpeg', body, 'binary', function(err){
        if (err) throw err
             console.log('File saved.')
         })
        res.send(200);
    });
});
```

However, when I try to convert it to base64 using a `Buffer` object and then send it to the client, the `img` tag does not recognize it as valid image data. This was confirmed using online utilites that show a preview of base64 image data.

Server:

```
res.send(new Buffer(body.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""), 'binary').toString('base64'));
```

Client:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 && xmlHttp.responseText != undefined) {
                var base64string = xmlHttp.responseText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
                document.getElementById('image').src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64string;
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", '/image', true);
        xmlHttp.send();
```

Edit: I removed the regex that removed the line breaks as pointed out. It did not help however.

Current Server:

```
res.send(new Buffer(body, 'binary').toString('base64'));
```

Current Client:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 && xmlHttp.responseText != undefined) {
                document.getElementById('image').src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", '/image', true);
        xmlHttp.send();
```

Comment: For the "Server," if the `body` represents the binary from a JPEG image, why are you replacing linebreaks as though it's a text file? Those bytes are significant in images.

Comment: You are correct. I removed the regex but that did not fix it. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> {encoding: 'binary'}

AFAIK if you want *request* to interpret response as a binary data, you should specify *encoding: null* instead.

(cite)

> **encoding** - Encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If null, 
>   the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the default 
>   value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter to toString() 
>   (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). (Note: if you expect binary 
>   data, you should set encoding: null.)

Once you do so the *body* you get in the response will be set to Buffer already, so you can just directly do:

```
body.toString('base64')
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
res.send(new Buffer(body.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""), 'binary').toString('base64'));
```

Doesn't make much sense, you aren't sending binary you are sending a string. So try.

```
res.send(new Buffer(body).toString('base64'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. The resulting string looks completely different from other images in base64 and still did not result in a valid image on the client.

Comment: I see the edit. Even with the line breaks intact before I convert it, the resulting data does not create a valid image.

Comment: Link to your image/data otherwise it's just guess work.